# nslookup on azure postgres server - output explanation

Tags: azure, postgresql, nslookup

I created a new postgres database in azure. Lets assume, this database has the server name URL `mytestdatabase.postgres.database.azure.com`
While doing a `nslookup` on this URL, i'll get the following informations:

```
nslookup mytestdatabase.postgres.database.azure.com
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

non-authoritative response:
Name:    cr1.ukwest1-a.control.database.windows.net
Address:  51.141.8.11
Aliases:  mytestdatabase.postgres.database.azure.com
          mytestdatabase.privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com
```

Is `cr1.ukwest1-a.control.database.windows.net` the server name of the data center and `51.141.8.11` the public ip of the gateway of this data center, or is `51.141.8.11` the public ip of my test postgres `mytestdatabase.postgres.database.azure.com`?

Comment: What does `dig mytestdatabase.postgres.database.azure.com` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Azure Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-connectivity-architecture)

> Connection to your Azure Database for PostgreSQL is established through a gateway that is responsible for routing incoming connections to the physical location of your server in our clusters. The following diagram illustrates the traffic flow.

[image]

So you're reaching to the gateway IP which then distributes the load to the clusters

Comment: And the gateway IP belongs to the data center cr1.ukwest1-a.control.database.windows.net ?

Comment: Not of the data center, of that gateway in the data center